# how does "Hitori hitori ga chiisana yume wo Daite kyou mo samayoi aruku " translates into this?

Tags: translation

I know that most translations arent literal, but can you help me understand this translation?

> Hitori hitori ga chiisana yume wo
>   Daite kyou mo samayoi aruku

it's subtitled in spanish as

"keep going for those small dreams, which one by one appear every day"

chiisana yume is "small dream" and the rest it doesnt make any sense to me

hitori I understand it is "one person"

daite "to hug or something more personal " is it another definition in this phrase?

kyou = today, fun, bad luck, etc. I dont know which one could be here.

samayoi = to wonder, to loiter . No idea which meaning has in the phrase

aruku = to walk

How all that translates to the former?

Comment: Where did you see/hear the Japanese?  It seems like it should be [い{L}だいて instead of だいて](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1873/78) when talking about your dreams.

Comment: youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGTe7sNvGfM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, *hitori hitori* ([[一人一人]{ひとりひとり}](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%B2%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8A%E3%81%B2%E3%81%A8%E3%82%8A)) is "each individual person".

Next, *daite* is the te-form of *daku* ([抱]{だ}く). Yes, its basic meaning is "to hug" but here its meaning is "to hold" or "to have".

*kyou* ([今日]{きょう}) is simply "today". so *kyou mo* means "today, too," which strongly implies the nuance of "as usual" and "without any change" here.

*samayoi* is the masu-stem of *samayou* ([彷徨]{さまよ}う) "to wander". So it connects adverbially to *aruku* ("to walk") here. So *samayoi aruku* is something like "walk while wandering" or "wander on foot". Note that the nuance of *samayou* is not going for a walk as a daily routine; it is more like to lose a goal and wander aimlessly.

---

So, the whole sentence literally translates as follows:

> Each person wanders on foot without an aim as usual today, holding a small dream.

---

One can say this in whatever ways they want, but I don't think "keep going for those small dreams, which one by one appear every day" is so good a translation. Small dreams do not appear every day.

Comment: thanks. that doesnt sound at all like the subtitle. Did the translator take way too much freedom to translate? – Pablo 10 mins ago

Comment: @Pablo I think the translation in the subtitles is incorrect...